# How to configure to display squiggle in the problem matcher of vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

There is a compiler that displays a compile result as below when fired error.

[image]

The message format is [File]:[Code]:[Line]:[Column]:[Serverity]:[Message]

I would like to display this to the problem panel so I constructed tasks.json as below.

[image]

As a result, it works fine but the squiggle is weird.
The squiggle has to be painted correctly under the token that error fired but be painted as below figure.

[image]

Is there additional data that the compiler has to provide or configure in the task.json to solve this problem?

Comment: if you only have a `line:char` position how do you expect to get a squiggle on a range

Comment: Yes, I also think it is weird but according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher in this example, it seems that there is no information other than line and column. Nevertheless, the squiggle is painted under 'prinft' token.

Comment: I have created a [doc issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/5177)

Comment: Thank you I will check the reply of the doc.